# Apply ColorFilter to a Drawable inside a LayerDrawable

Tags: android, colorfilter, layerdrawable

I want to have two cars in different colors (let's say red and blue) displayed at the same time for my game and to do so I use the same `LayerDrawable` (which is set as an image resource to an `ImageView`) for both cars:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/car_backstuff"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/car_body"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/car_frontstuff"/>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that when I want to color a car, I  do it like this:

```
_layerDrawable.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);_
```

but when I do that for the second car (i.e with `Color.BLUE`) **BOTH** cars become blue !

I knew that this is because it refers the same resource (R.drawable.car_body in that case) but I want to know if there is a way to apply a `ColorFilter` different for each car like insert another layer on top of the car body and multiply it or something ?

Comment: @Hamid Shatu instead of just edit my post.. can you answer it ? Or even try to ?

Comment: @Vyger yep you're right and I wasn't pretending he knows the solution but "Just edited your question, sorry can't answer it" would be enough, but nevermind. Considering the answer, I am thinking about 'mutate' the color `Drawable`, is that good ?

Comment: @Der Golem, this worked for me, although it feels a bit unwieldy.  I could get my drawable to change color, but it's dimensions were changing too, I think because it is a shape inside an inset. So, having a separate layer list for each color works in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question:

The solution is to call `mutate()` for the `LayerDrawable` and after that any changes on a `Drawable` inside it will not be repercuted to the other one which use the same resource, that's magic !